# Website contact form not receiving messages

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

Very new html and website developer and unsure why my current contact box is not working. I'm hosting it my own website and when I do attempt to send I get a message sent response but the emails are never received.

I have't eliminated the email hosting being broken by using multiple email addresses to send and receive from but have been unable to get find the source of the problem.

See relevant code bellow

main.js

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

sendemail.php

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));  
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = '\\myemailaddress//';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
     <div class="contact-form bottom">
           <h2>Send a message</h2>
                <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Your text here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Submit">
                       </div>
               </form>
       </div>
</div>
```

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: I deleted my answer. I guess that didn't serve you at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After work from @charlietfl answer. Changing the type and url seemed to fix it. 
Working code underneath :

main.js:

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form').serialize();
form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

and my .php

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: '); 
    $status = array( 
        'type'=>'success', 
        'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you ' 
    ); 

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));  
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));  
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));  
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));  

$email_from = $email; 
$email_to = '\\myemail//'; 

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message; 

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>'); 

echo json_encode($status); 
die;
```

Answer (score 1):

Next issue is you aren't sending any data with your ajax. Using `$(formSelector).serialize()` simplifies gathering the data

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    //serialize form data and include it with request
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        ...
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    ....
});
```

Currently if you did `print_r($_POST);` in your php you would see it is empty

Comment: I take it this will be a joint venture lol ;-) TBH, Ajax/jQuery isn't my forté so I wouldn't have been able to spot problems with it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- was simple to spot really... not many lines of options in `$.ajax` means something's missing  ...lol.

Comment: hehe, for you maybe. I'm still reading a book on jQuery. I've been out of touch with it for too long. When I found PHP, I gave up on JS because that just boggled my mind; it still does.

Comment: I'll let the OP piece it all together, I think they have enough to go on. *Cheers*

Comment: want to see an exact duplicate that just got posted? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34834475/ and I deleted my answer. I guess it didn't serve them.

Comment: This got me on the right track but won't receive the body of the messages just a empty email. Manged to get it now. Thanks a bunch